# how to start animation one after the another using thread for image view?

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, view, imageview

In my android application i need to animate the image view one after another i have four image view animation should proceed **one after another for the image view**

i have tried using thread

```
            iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    iv3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    iv4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            animSlideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.slide_up);
            mSplashThread1 =  new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        synchronized(this){
                            // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                            wait(5000);
                            iv3.startAnimation(animSlideUp);
                        }
                    } 
                    catch(InterruptedException ex){                 
                    }

                    finish();

                }
            };
            // The thread to wait for splash screen events
            mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        synchronized(this){
                            // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                            wait(5000);
                            iv2.startAnimation(animSlideUp);
                        }
                    } 
                    catch(InterruptedException ex){                 
                    }

                    finish();
                    mSplashThread1.start();             
                }
            };

            mSplashThread.start();
            // The thread to wait for splash screen events
```

i have used two thread to start animation
plz help me i am new to android

Answer (score 2):

You can use different values for

```
android:startOffset="100"
```

in animation xml file under res/anim folder for all four animations with the delay(in ms) value you want to use. In case you need help with how to use xml animations, [here](http://mariodinata.com/android-slide-up-down-animation/) is a tutorial for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html). 
Try the following code:

```
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

            animSlideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.slide_up);

            animSlideUp.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                     animSlideUp.setAnimationListener(null);
                     iv3.startAnimation(animSlideUp);

                }
            });

            iv2.startAnimation(animSlideUp);

        }
```

Comment: i tried to start but the animation is in parallel it should start one after another

Comment: Try the edited answer. No need to use thread to delay animation.
You can also define animation offset values in xml to delay it.